# how to prepare a method/function call for to calling it in a later point?

Tags: php, oop

which is the best way to "prepare/store a function call"* for to, in a later point, actually execute it?

(* with an undetermined number of parameters)

what I have now:

```
function addCall($className, [$parameter [, $parameter ...]]) 
{ 
    $this->calls[] = func_get_args();
}
```

then I'll do:

```
foreach($this->calls as $args) 
{ 
    $r = new ReflectionClass(array_shift($args));
    $instances[] = $r->newInstanceArgs($args);
}
```

which doesn't look very OOP to me, including the "undetermined number of parameters" characteristic

how can I improve my code?

thank you in advance

Comment: I'd personally just use `call_user_func_array`, but that looks even worse from an OOP standpoint. However, it should work for what you're trying to do.

Comment: I was wondering which is the best way to write this concept in a "pure" oop way... without using reflection or call_user_func*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be interested in the [Command pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern).
How you implement it is up to you - or the framework you're using.
But those patterns usually stack up. So have a good read of the "surrounding" patterns, too, to be able to make a good choice regarding the actual implementation (or choosing an existing library).

completely informal:

```
<?php
function foo($a, $b) {
    return 'foo#'.($a+$b);
}

function bar($a,$b,$c) {
    return 'bar#'.($a-$b+$c);
}

$cmds = array();
$cmds[] = function() { return foo(1,2); };
$cmds[] = function() { return bar(1,2,3); };
$cmds[] = function() { return bar(5,6,7); };
$cmds[] = function() { return foo(9,7); };
$s = new stdClass; $s->x = 8; $s->y = 8;
$cmds[] = function() use($s) { return foo($s->x,$s->y); };


// somewhere else....
foreach($cmds as $c) {
    echo $c(), "\n";
}
```

or something like

```
<?php
interface ICommand {
    public function /* bool */ Execute();
}

class Foo implements ICommand {
    public function __construct($id) {
        $this->id = $id;
    }
    public function Execute() {
        echo "I'm Foo ({$this->id})\n";
        return true;
    }
}

class Bar implements ICommand {
    public function __construct($id) {
        $this->id = $id;
    }
    public function Execute() {
        echo "I'm Bar ({$this->id})\n";
        return true;
    }
}

$queueCommands = new SplPriorityQueue();

$queueCommands->insert(new Foo('lowPrio'), 1);
$queueCommands->insert(new Foo('midPrio'), 2);
$queueCommands->insert(new Foo('highPrio'), 3);
$queueCommands->insert(new Bar('lowPrio'), 1);
$queueCommands->insert(new Bar('midPrio'), 2);
$queueCommands->insert(new Bar('highPrio'), 3);

// somewhere else....
foreach( $queueCommands as $cmd ) {
    if ( !$cmd->execute() ) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

or something else ...

Comment: +1, good explanation and recommending a valuable design pattern. Check also ircmaxell's "Programming with Anthony" video about that: http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2013/02/design-patterns-programming-with-anthony.html